# Is it possible to match two different Data types in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I want to compare two field values from different tables of PostgreSQL both are of different data types that is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS departments(
  _id SERIAL NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
  departmentName text,
  active BOOLEAN
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS departments_users(
  _id SERIAL NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
  department_id integer[]
);

INSERT INTO departments(_id,departmentName)
VALUES
    ( 1, 'aa' ),
    ( 2, 'bb' ),
    ( 3, 'cc' ),
    ( 4, 'dd' );

INSERT INTO departments_users(_id,department_id)
VALUES
  ( 1, ARRAY[1,2,3] );
```

in the above 2nd table am using department_id which are all present in departments table but in second table am storing it in array if i want get the data which has the common department id 
expected output should be:

```
_id | departmentName
-----------------------
1   | aa
2   | bb
3   | cc
```

So is it possible to match 2 different datatypes?

Comment: `_id = ANY(department_id)` should work I think.

Comment: The question doesn't actually reflect this situation. The data TYPES aren't different, the method of storage (singular versus in an array) are what's different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with either `ANY` as mentioned in @ypercube's comment, or with `<@` (the containment operator)

```
SELECT *
FROM departments
JOIN departments_users
  ON departments._id = ANY(department_id);
 _id | departmentname | active | _id | department_id 
-----+----------------+--------+-----+---------------
   1 | aa             |        |   1 | {1,2,3}
   2 | bb             |        |   1 | {1,2,3}
   3 | cc             |        |   1 | {1,2,3}
(3 rows)
```

If that doesn't work with an index you may need.

```
SELECT *
FROM departments
JOIN departments_users
  ON department_id @> ARRAY[departments._id];
```